# How can i can display fields from an item from Collection B referenced by an id from an item from Collection A?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

i have two collections

```
CategoryCollection = new Mongo.Collection("CategoryCollection");
usersWordpressCollection = new Mongo.Collection("usersWordpressCollection");
```

CategoryCollection hold posts within a category, within the posts objects there is the Author, which comes as an id. take a look at the image below, draw your attention to **posts.author**

[image]

usersWordpressCollection holds the authors whose **id** (see image below) is referenced in categoryCollection under **posts.author**

[image]

when i display a post, its coming from `categoryCollection` so i can get the post, the link etc. i can also get the author id however when it comes to this, i want to return, not the id, but the referenced Author information found in the `usersWordpressCollection`

**latest html**

```
<template name="latest">

  <ul>
      {{#each articles}}
        <li class=" home-latest ">
            <span class="label">  <a class="" href="/catsingle/CategorySingle/{{_id}}">{{name}}</a></span>
        {{#each posts}}
          <div class="card">
            <div class="category-img">{{{image}}}</div>
          <div class="card-divider">
          {{title}}
          </div>
          <div class="card-section">
          <p>
            {{> authors}}
          </p>
          </div>
          </div>

      </li>
        {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

**latest js**

```
Template.latest.helpers({
  articles: function () {
    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id');
    return CategoryCollection.find({}, {sort: {date_created: -1}, limit:1}).fetch();
  }
});
```

**authors html**

```
<template name="authors">

{{#each authors}}
<p>
  {{name}}
</p>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

authors js

```
Template.authors.helpers({
  authors: function () {
  var id = this.author;
 console.log(id);
var alias = usersWordpressCollection.findOne(id, {fields: {name: 1} });
return alias.name;
console.log(alias.name);
});
```

As you can see, `this.author` is the author **id** found in `categoryCollection` `posts.author`. Im trying to find that **id** in the `usersWordpressCollection` matching the author, then i want to display the `name field` of the Author whose **id** was matched. but i can't seen to get it working, how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is only one author per post you don't need to iterate over a cursor of authors, you only need one. So where you have:

```
{{#each authors}}
  <p>
    {{name}}
  </p>
{{/each}}
```

Instead use:

```
{{#with author}}
  <p>
    {{name}}
  </p>
{{/with}}
```

Now, the data context coming into the `authors` template will be a `post` object (since you are within an `{{#each posts}}`. You can therefore construct your `author` helper as follows:

```
Template.authors.helpers({
  author(){
    return usersWordpressCollection.findOne({ id: parseInt(this.author) });
  }
});
```

Since you've indicated that `this.author` is a string but the `id` of your user collection is an integer then you need to convert the type - you can do this directly in your query.

Comment: Hi @Michel, i can't seem to get it working, i wonder, would this have an impact? `this.author`  is a string which i'm trying to match to `id` which is an integer. one is a string, the other is an integer,

Comment: Then do `id = parseInt(this.author)` and search on that.

Comment: i'm sorry for my ignorance, where do i put that code exactly? I understand that `parseInt` is making `this.author` into an integer, but is `id` a variable i have to set? where deos that code go? @Michel

Comment: Yes! that works now. this is a solution i can use with other pain points, thanks for that. @Michel